# is it possible for each vertex in a graph to have odd degree? when? Even degree?

Tags: graph-theory

I know that there can't be an odd number of odd degree and in any graph number of odd degree vertices is an even number but is it possible for each vertex in a graph to have an odd degree and when?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every graph with at least one vertex of odd degree has an even number of vertices of odd degree, by your remark. Since zero is even as well, every graph has an even number of vertices of odd degree.

Answer (score 4):

The order of all the vertices of $K_n$, the complete graph of order $n$ is odd if $n$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

[image: The graph]

Here is a tiny example – one edge, two vertices each with degree $1$.